# What could cause duplicate rows in fetched Google Analytics reports?

Tags: google-analytics-api

I'm working on a tool to fetch about 3 years of historic data from a site, in order to perform some data analysis & machine learning.

The dimensions of the report I am requesting are:

`[ ga:cityId, ga:dateHour, ga:userType, ga:deviceCategory ]`

And my starting point is to import to a postgres db (the data may live elsewhere eventually but we have Good Reasons for starting with a relational database).

I've defined a unique index on the `[ ga:cityId, ga:dateHour, ga:userType, ga:deviceCategory ]` tuple for the postgres table, and my import job currently routinely fails every 30000-50000 rows due to a duplicate of that tuple.

What would cause google to return duplicate rows?

I'm batching the inserts by 1000 rows / statement because row-at-a-time would be very time consuming, so I think my best workaround is to disable the unique index for the duration of the initial import, de-dupe, and then re-enable it and do daily imports of fresh data row-at-a-time. Other strategies?

Comment: I probably just got unlucky in my initial testing -- my date range enddate was "live", and the page boundaries probably changed in between page fetches.  When running with a period with end date more than 24h in the past, we haven't seen duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be duplicate reports coming back from google if the time ranges are unique.

Are you using absolute or relative (to present) dates? If the latter, you should ensure that changes in the time period cause by the progression of the relative time (ie the present) don't cause an overlap.

Using relative time period could also cause gaps in your data.

Comment: more or less what I think was happening -- end of the time range was "Now" and tests happened to span the time new data came in, causing page boundaries to shift.